# How do I update or add field in a list item so that the value is a space character

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, event-handlers, features

I am building an event handler. When items in a library on one server farm are updated or deleted, I take that information and ammend a list that resides on another site. I require that one of the fields "Search" contains a space character. Only that, nothing else. I have tried the following 4 different methods with no success. The item gets created or updated but the 'Search' field is blank, whereas it needs to hold a space character. I'm stumped.

```
    "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
    "<Field Name='ID'>IDVALUEOFITEM</Field>" +
    "<Field Name='Search'> </Field></Method>" +

    "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
    "<Field Name='ID'>IDVALUEOFITEM</Field>" +
    "<Field Name='Search'>" + "&nbsp;" + "</Field></Method>" +

    "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
    "<Field Name='ID'>IDVALUEOFITEM</Field>" +
    "<Field Name='Search'>" + "<![CDATA[ ]]>" + "</Field></Method>" +

    "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
    "<Field Name='ID'>IDVALUEOFITEM</Field>" +
    "<Field Name='Search'>" + "&#160;" + "</Field></Method>" +
```

Without quotes around the various items eg. " " I get a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a wild guess, but what happens when you try:

```
"<Field Name='Search'>' '</Field></Method>" +
```

or even

```
"<Field Name='Search'>"+" "+"</Field></Method>" +
```

oooh, or what about

```
"<Field Name='Search'>"+"%20"+"</Field></Method>" +
```

Comment: I have tried
" "
I think I tried "%20" as well, but I can't recall so I will try %20 and ' ' thanks for the suggestions. I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok so, "+"%20"+" and ' ' put in the literal strings ' ' and %20 in that field on the target list. 
:\